# Crawling using Nutch...Shows an IOException

Tags: java, open-source, web-crawler, nutch, ioexception

I've started using Nutch and everything was fine until I encountered an `IOException` exception,

```
$ ./nutch crawl urls -dir myCrawl -depth 2 -topN 4
cygpath: can't convert empty path
solrUrl is not set, indexing will be skipped...
crawl started in: myCrawl
rootUrlDir = urls
threads = 10
depth = 2
solrUrl=null
topN = 4
Injector: starting at 2012-06-23 03:37:51
Injector: crawlDb: myCrawl/crawldb
Injector: urlDir: urls
Injector: Converting injected urls to crawl db entries.
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to set permissions of path: \tmp\hadoop-Rahul\mapred\staging\Rahul255889423\.staging to 0700
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.checkReturnValue(FileUtil.java:682)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.setPermission(FileUtil.java:655)
    at      org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:509)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.mkdirs(FilterFileSystem.java:189)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:116)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:856)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:850)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1083)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:850)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:824)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1261)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.inject(Injector.java:217)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl.run(Crawl.java:127)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl.main(Crawl.java:55)
```

---

@jeffery ---    i downgraded my nutch version n encountered a new problem,which is out of my scope to understand....
Plzz help....

```
$ ./nutch crawl urls -dir myCrawl -depth 4 -topN 5
cygpath: can't convert empty path
solrUrl is not set, indexing will be skipped...
crawl started in: myCrawl
root UrlDir = urls
threads = 10
depth = 4
solrUrl=null
topN = 5
Injector: starting at 2012-06-23 22:30:28
Injector: crawlDb: myCrawl/crawldb
Injector: urlDir: urls
Injector: Converting injected urls to crawl db entries.
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Job failed!
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1252)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.inject(Injector.java:217)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl.run(Crawl.java:127)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl.main(Crawl.java:55)
```

What's the problem this tym???

Comment: Which version of Nutch / Hadoop are you using?

Comment: dont know abt hadoop.
I'm a complete noob in using Nutch. :(

Comment: I referre to these 3 videos link... 
Part1) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=baxhI6Wkov8&feature=channel&list=UL
Part2) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qs-18hRRpNU
Part3) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GtbDHiYrlNE

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error while crawling using Nutch 1.4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169243/error-while-crawling-using-nutch-1-4)

Comment: the problem for me was solved after i removed hadoop-core-1.0.3.jar from the lib folder and replaced it with hadoop-core-0.20.2.jar file

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem a couple days ago as well. The newer versions of Hadoop have trouble when it comes to interacting with Windows. You can either switch over to a *nix platform (which you should probably do, almost all of the support for Nutch is aimed at *nix users) or downgrade your version Nutch. The newest version of Nutch which I found to work on Windows Server 2008 was [1.2](http://archive.apache.org/dist/nutch/).

Comment: thnx for the info....
if i downgrade the version to 1.2 under windows, will it hv any sort of limitations as compared to working under linux environment using the newest version of nutch???

Comment: @prafulbagai You will not have any of the new features. All of the official tutorials are geared towards 1.5, so there may be some discrepancies. You will still be able to crawl, parse and index, so depending on the exact nature of your needs it may be fine.

Comment: Thnx Jeffery!!!! Gonna try wat u recommended!!!
1 last question.. This may sound kinda stupid but If i want to review the source code of Nutch n customize it ,where can i hv it from???

Comment: @prafulbagai There should be a download option for `apache-nutch-#.#-src.(zip/tar.gz)`. That will include the source code.

Comment: @jeffery---can u please tell wat error is this???
I hv downgraded it to 1.4 n now its all a different story...
Please help!!!

The error is posted below!!!
Thnx